# Log all User Changes as an Event Log [Write-EventLog]

Tags: powershell

I am trying to log all user changes (Creating a new user, changing password and removing a user) into an Event Log (Write-EventLog)
For example I changed the password:

```
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "new_password" -AsPlainText -Force
Set-LocalUser -Name "usre_name" -Password $NewPassword
```

Now how can I log this change into Event Log using Write-Event?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What does the __5.__ on your title stand for? Is this some sort of homework maybe?

Comment: All these events are already recorded by Windows by the way, you don't really need to register new ones. i.e.: Event ID 4720 for account creation. You just need to do at least some research.